# D3: How can I change data in an existing bar chart

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, updates

I have successfully build my initial bar chart. Now I want to add more bars to that existing chart using transitions to have a nice user experience.

Here's my code:

```
var data = [23, 85, 67, 38, 70]; //dummy, normally much more
labellist = ['label1','label2','label3','label4','label5'];

var w = 815,
    h = 500,
    labelpad = 165,
    x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]).range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(d3.range(data.length)).rangeBands([0, h], .2);

mySvg = d3.select("#chart")
  .append("svg");

vis = mySvg.attr("width", w + 40)
    .attr("height", h + 20)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)");

bars = vis.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + labelpad + "," + y(i) + ")"; })


bars.append("svg:rect")

    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    ;



var rules = vis.selectAll("g.rule")
    .data(x.ticks(10))
  .enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "rule")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d) + ", 0)"; });

rules.append("svg:line")
    .attr("y1", h)
    .attr("y2", h + 6)
    .attr("x1", labelpad)
    .attr("x2", labelpad)
    .attr("stroke", "black");
rules.append("svg:line")
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("y2", h)
    .attr("x1", labelpad)
    .attr("x2", labelpad)
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("stroke-opacity", .3);
```

How can I programmatically change the data to add and remove other bars and let the existing ones slide up/down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign some form of key to the bars' data so d3 can identify ones that existed in the previous set. The default is index-based, and that may be what you want.

As far as the transitions go, you want to change your code to something like this:

```
bars = vis.selectAll("g.bar")
    .data(data);

bars.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .append("svg:rect").

bars.transition().duration(500)
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { 
         return "translate(" + labelpad + "," + y(i) + ")"; 
     })
    .selectAll("svg:rect")
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
;

bars.exit().transition().duration(500)
    .selectAll("svg:rect")
    .attr("height", 0)
    .remove();
```

The "enter()" function is best used to create the structure immediately. Then use the initial selection object (bars) to apply the new data to all elements.

You also probably want to remove any obsolete bars. Here I've resized them to 0 and then removed them, but you can tinker with it to get the effect you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm new to d3 - do you know of any tutorial or example showing the use of the keys you mentioned? What would my updateChart() function look like?
When I try your code for transitions the chart is not displayed, I get a "Uncaught Error: SYNTAX_ERR: DOM Exception 12" in d3.v2.js at d3_selection(groups) (I already fixed your typo in the second call, period instead of semicolon)

Comment: I haven't run this code, so there's likely other issues with it. I was just trying to show you the idea of using enter/exit functions for add/remove of elements.

Comment: This is a good one with bar charts, showing how to nicely add bars: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html